# Code for acos with avx256?

Tags: intrinsics, avx2, trigonometry

I have to call the **acos** method for every pixel of an image.

I am using avx2.

Is there _mm256 code for acos apart from the libraries provided with the intel c++ compiler?

Comment: How much error are you willing to accept?  There's a tradeoff between speed and precision for complicated functions like acos.

Comment: @Peter Cordes  A precision of 0.01% to 0.5% would suffice. If there is an approximation with stopping criterion this could be determined in a flexible way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inverse cosine over 0.0 .. 1.0 looks like `sqrt(1 - x) * pi/2`, not exactly of course, but here's that multiplied by a polynomial in `x` to compensate:

```
__m256 acos(__m256 x) {
    __m256 xp = _mm256_and_ps(x, _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_set1_epi32(0x7FFFFFFF)));
    // main shape
    __m256 one = _mm256_set1_ps(1.0);
    __m256 t = _mm256_sqrt_ps(_mm256_sub_ps(one, xp));
    // polynomial correction factor based on xp
    __m256 c3 = _mm256_set1_ps(-0.02007522);
    __m256 c2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(xp, c3, _mm256_set1_ps(0.07590315));
    __m256 c1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(xp, c2, _mm256_set1_ps(-0.2126757));
    __m256 c0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(xp, c1, _mm256_set1_ps(1.5707963267948966));
    // positive result
    __m256 p = _mm256_mul_ps(t, c0);
    // correct for negative x
    __m256 n = _mm256_sub_ps(_mm256_set1_ps(3.14159265359), p);
    return _mm256_blendv_ps(p, n, x);
}
```

The polynomial was made by fixing the 0th coefficient at pi/2 and applying a least-squares fit to find the others. So it's not a min-maxed polynomial, and likely a better one could be found. I have compared it exhaustively to `std::acosf` in MSVC2017 (though the accuracy of `std::acosf` itself is not specified). The maximum absolute error is 8.45194e-05 and occurs (for example) at 0.106028. The maximum relative error is 1.87481e-04 and occurs close to (but not at) 1.

Comment: Works like a charm (out of the box!).